# What are the pros and cons to use iPhone/Android phones to write scripts?

Tags: iphone, android, scripting, text-editor

What are the the positive and negative attributes to use iPhone/Android phones to write scripts?

I'd like to buy a new mobile phone which I can utilize my time to do some scripting even when I'm not at my desktop computer.

I heard that you can't save files to your iPhone unless you jail break it. This maybe a big problem if I want to create some new scripting file. Say I want to create a abc.java and there's no way for me to save it.

Is it the same case for Android too? Can I create local scripting files on Android phones? Since Android is a linux os.

**Is it possible to install java sdk or other sdk (like flex?) on it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about it.

The iPhone is obviously too closed. Android let you do whatever you want (and when not, getting root access is piece of cake) but there is no dev env, only java is installed, available shells are REALLY  poor and eventually  the keyboard / screen size will drive you mad.

writting this only answer took me 10 minutes on my HTC dream and I am only willing to do it because I am stuck in a very boring conference.

Answer (score 2):

There are text editors for the iPhone that save inside there own application space, and can sync with a PC.

That said, I don't think you'd find typing scripts on a handheld device to be a particularly productive environment.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to [create files on the file system](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) using the Android SDK - without root access - both within your application sandbox or on the SD card.

It would theoretically be possible to write a program that compiles or executes those files, though trying to create a reasonable development environment for Android applications on an Android device is probably stretching your luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that iPhones do not expose the filesystem to users (see [this article](http://www.macworld.com/article/133971/2008/06/iphone_open_save.html)).  Of course, there are loopholes around this, but none of them are convenient.   It is supposed to be easier to [gain access](http://www.saurik.com/id/10) to a real Linux shell with Android.  In theory you could install SDKs with some work, but I don't think you'd find it an efficient development environment.

Comment: Is it possible to create local files on Anrdoid without the root access then? if yes, then does it mean that you can even write a problem that compile those local files?

Comment: You can read/write files on the SD card without root access, and do whatever you want with them. You could potentially port a compiler of some kind to android and build a complete IDE there. Not a trivial task, though.

Answer (score 1):

I found that writing scripts on the Android pretty cool and very convient. The best part is the ability to cut and paste. I use a text editor and it allows you save as any file extension to your sd card. So far I've been able to edit php files and upload using a ftp app. You can even ssh into your remote server.

I don't think there's an SDK for the Android.